# Refactor: Javascript block

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

Need some help refactoring this code:

```
$("span[rel=color_content]").ColorPicker({
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
    $("span[rel=color_content]").css('background-color', '#' + hex);
  }
});
$("span[rel=color_link]").ColorPicker({
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
    $("span[rel=color_link]").css('background-color', '#' + hex);
  }
});
$("span[rel=color_selected]").ColorPicker({
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
    $("span[rel=color_selected]").css('background-color', '#' + hex);
  }
});
$("span[rel=color_page]").ColorPicker({
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
    $("span[rel=color_page]").css('background-color', '#' + hex);
  }
});
$("span[rel=color_player]").ColorPicker({
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
    $("span[rel=color_player]").css('background-color', '#' + hex);
  }
});
```

The only thing changing between each is the contents of the `rel` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
function setColorPicker(css_selector) {
    $(css_selector).ColorPicker({
      onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
         $(css_selector).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// Newlines added for readability
$('span[rel=color_content],
   span[rel=color_link],
   span[rel=color_selected],
   span[rel=color_page],
   span[rel=color_player]').ColorPicker({
       onChange: function(hsb, hex, rg){
           $(this).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
       }
   });
```

I'm guessing there's only one instance of each span on the page. If not, you can modify this slightly to get something that behaves the same way:

```
// Newlines added for readability
$('span[rel=color_content],
   span[rel=color_link],
   span[rel=color_selected],
   span[rel=color_page],
   span[rel=color_player]').ColorPicker({
       onChange: function(hsb, hex, rg){
           $('span[rel='+$(this).attr('rel')+']')
               .css('background-color', '#' + hex);
       }
   });
```

Comment: The OP code changes the background-color for the entire list of elements (the entire selector), not just the one that was changed

Comment: @Šime - Added a second part to the answer to address that (even though I don't think that is the intent).

Comment: 1. Maybe `$('span').filter('[rel=foo], [rel=bar], ...')` 2. `this.rel` is safe, no need for attr()

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in ['content','link','selected','page','player'])
{
    $("span[rel=color_"+i+"]").ColorPicker({   
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {$("span[rel=color_"+i+"]").css('background-color', '#' + hex);   } }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
    'color_content',
    'color_link', 
    'color_selected', 
    'color_page', 
    'color_player'
];
```

---

```
function foo() {
    var i, selector;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        selector = 'span[rel=' + arr[i] + ']';

        $(selector).ColorPicker({
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rg) {
                $(selector).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you end up with a really long list of these to maintain, one way is to put all the changing information in one easily-maintainable variable:

```
var rels = ['color_content','color_link','color_selected','color_page'];
```

Then you could have:

```
// build the selectors according to your patterh
var selectors = $.map( rels, function(e,i){ 
  return 'span[rel=' + rels + ']'; 
}).join(',');

$(selectors).ColorPicker({
  onChange: function(hsb,hex,rg){
    $(this).css('background-color','#'+hex); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can separate several CSS selectors using a comma:

```
$("span[rel=color_player], span[rel=color_page]").ColorPicker();
```